# C Convert char into char*

Tags: c, char, type-conversion

I have a `char` that is given from `fgets`, and I would like to know how I can convert it into a `char*`.

I am sure this has been posted before, but I couldn't find one that was doing quite what I wanted to do. Any answer is appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the code.

```
char *filename = "file.txt";
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
if(file != NULL) {
  char line[260];
  char *fl;
  while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
    // here I combine some strings with the 'line' variable.
    str_replace(line, "\"", "\"\""); // A custom function, but it only takes char*'s.
  }
  printf(fl);
  printf("\n");
} else {
  printf(" -- *ERROR* Couldn't open file.\n");
}
```

Comment: No, you don't.  `fgets()` returns a `char*` result, not a `char`.  Please give us a better idea of what you're trying to do, preferably by posting some actual code.

Comment: Oh. My mistake. That means that I don't really need this question anymore.

Comment: Then you can (and should) delete the question yourself.

Comment: @KeithThompson It has an upvoted answer, OP can't delete it anymore.

Comment: `#define TOCHARARRAY(c) ({ \
   char arr[] = { c, 0 }; \
    arr;     \
   })`

Comment: @Jack: That uses an "expression statement", which is a non-standard gcc extension.

Comment: Matthew: I see there's an upvoted answer that you've accepted. I'm not sure how it applies, though. Perhaps you can edit the question so it's more closely related to what you were looking for? At least the first sentence of your question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, first of all, `line` is an array of `char`s and so can be manipulated in much the same way as a `char *` (See [comp.lang.c FAQs](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) for important differences), so you don't need to worry about it.

However, in case you want an answer to the general question...

The `&` operator is what you need:

```
char c;
char *pChar = &c;
```

However, bear in mind that pChar is a pointer to the char and will only be valid while c is in scope. That means that you can't return pChar from a function and expect it to work; it will be pointing to some part of the heap and you can't expect that to stay valid.

If you want to pass it as a return value, you will need to malloc some memory and then use the pointer to write the value of c:

```
char c;
char *pChar = malloc(sizeof(char));

/* check pChar is not null */

*pChar = c;
```

Comment: "`line` is a `char *`, since it's an array of `char`s" -- No, arrays are not pointers. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Comment: @KeithThompson: "... though they are closely related". [Question 6.2](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

Comment: Question 6.2 make it very clear that they're entirely distinct concepts. Yes, they're closely related; so are a lot of concepts in any programming language. There's a widespread misconception that C arrays are really pointers; let's not add to it.

Comment: Good on generalizing, but I think this answer would be a lot better if it used an array of two chars, with c as the first and NUL as the second, showing how to "convert" a char to a NUL-terminated string... edit: Ah, I see Daniel did just that ...

Answer (score 9):

Using the `&` operator will give you a pointer to the character, as Dancrumb mentioned, but there is the problem of scope preventing you from returning the pointer, also as he mentioned.

One thing that I have to add is that I imagine that the reason you want a `char*` is so that you can use it as a string in `printf` or something similar. You cannot use it in this way because the string will not be `NULL` terminated. To convert a `char` into a string, you will need to do something like

```
char c = 'a';
char *ptr = malloc(2*sizeof(char));
ptr[0] = c;
ptr[1] = '\0';
```

Don't forget to free `ptr` later!

Comment: malloc argument: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by std; you can write only: `malloc(2)` that is equivalent to.

Comment: @Jack, is there any particular reason to do that, though, rather than following the usual formula of using `sizeof`?

Comment: It seems unnecessarily verbose to convert a count of chars into a count of bytes when char is mandated to be a byte. Would you write `malloc((strlen(foo)+1)*sizeof(char))` when allocating space for a copy of `foo`? In any case, I prefer `foo = malloc(n*sizeof *foo)`, which works regardless of the type of foo.